# Show that $Gal(x^4+ax^2+b)\leq D_8$ .

Tags: galois-theory

> Let $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x^2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})\leq D_8$ where $D_8$ is a dihedral group with 8 elements.

I feel like there should be more information. What I have tried is to classify all possible situation, for example, when $f(x^2)$ split completely, when $f(x^2)$ is irreducible, when $f(x^2)$ is factored into two quadratic polynomials and when $f(x^2)$ factored into one linear and one cubic.  But I always ended up to use discriminant or resolvant cubic which seems too arbitrary considering arbitrary $a$ and $b$. Is this problem possible to be proved?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(x^2)$ will not split into one linear and one cubic: If $(x-a)|f(x^2)$ then $(x+a)|f(x^2)$.

Comment: @HwChu Oh that is right!  Thanks that is good point!

Comment: Suppose $f(x^2)$ has distinct roots. Let $G$ be the Galois group of the splitting field, which is a subgroup of $S_4$ acting on the four roots. If $\sigma \in G$ has order $3$ it stabilizes exactly one root. But if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x^2)$ then so is $-\alpha$, and $\sigma \alpha = \alpha$ implies $\sigma (-\alpha) = -\alpha$. So $G$ has no element of order $3$, and so must be a $2$-group, and so must be contained in the $2$-Sylow $D_8$ of $S_4$. The case when $f(x^2)$ has repeated roots is even easier, since it implies $f(x^2) = (x^2 - a)^2$ with $a \in \mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: In general, if $f(x)$ of degree $n$ is separable, then the Galois group of $f(x^2)$ is contained in $S_2 \wr S_n$ because $G$ acts imprimitively on the roots in $n$ pairs of $2$ roots $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$.

Comment: @user687721 That is clear! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user687721 Could I ask what do you mean by $S_2 ≀S_n$?

Comment: It's the wreath product. It's easier than writing it as the semidirect product $(S_2)^{n} \rtimes S_n$. In this case, if you think of the roots as $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n, - \alpha_n, \ldots, - \alpha_1$, then it's the subgroup of bijections $\sigma \in S_{2n}$ such that $\sigma(k) + \sigma(2n+1-k) = 2n+1$.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that the splitting field of $f(x)$ has Galois group a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$, and the splitting field of $f(x^2)$ is just given by adjoining the roots, so if $G \subset S_{2n}$ is the Galois group then the kernel of $G \rightarrow H$ just comes from taking squareroots so is an elementary $2$-group.